# Program pic32 without a pickit

Tags: pic, jtag

Is there a way to program (flash) bare (not already flashed with a bootloader) pic32 chips without using a pickit-type programmer?

Are there any ongoing projects for JTAG, for example?

Comment: What is your more specific definition of a pickit-type programmer? One that is a specific clone of the pickit programmer or any programmer that uses hardware ?

Comment: Any programmer that uses that particular ISP method/port.

Comment: Discovered https://github.com/GBert/CP2104_GPIO with an interesting option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggest you refer to the Microchip PIC32 family programming documentation [here](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/61129F.pdf).
According to it:

> 33.2.1.3 DEVICE PROGRAMMING USING THE JTAG INTERFACE
>
> The JTAG interface can also be used to program PIC32 devices in their target
> applications. The JTAG interface allows application designers to
> include a dedicated test and programming port into their applications,
> with a single 4-pin interface, without imposing the circuit
> constraints that the ICSP interface may require.

So according to the documentation, you have an alternative to the standard Microchip ISP.

Comment: I've seen comments relating to pic32 on OpenOCD list as well. I'll look into it on my copious free time.

Answer (score 1):

Presently JTAG cannot be used for programming (flash programming)DSPIC32 series.The same information is mentioned in the datasheet.

Comment: This applies to the **ds** pic?